# Unable to understand difference between the options in Symbology Pane in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

It's quite difficult to understand and explain the difference between the two options shown below.

When I tried exploring they both (Anchor points and Offsets) move the features in an opposite way, and I can use only one option to get the desired results, but what is the difference between these two options?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on similar terminology elsewhere, rather than specific to ArcGIS.  But I believe it is likely to be the same.

The "Anchor Point" is the graphics point within the symbol graphic itself that represents the location of the symbol (ie, the point of the symbol graphic that should be used to represent the location on the map).  So for a cross symbol, you would usually want the centre point of the symbol graphic.  But for a pin symbol, you would want the bottom Y coordinate and the middle X coordinate of the symbol graphic.

The Offset is how close to the map location the anchor point should be.  Usually this would be 0,0 but there may be some situations where you don't want the symbol (or its anchor point) placed precisely on the map location that it represents.

In practice, these settings appear to behave similarly (but appear to move the symbol in opposite directions to each other).  But there are a few differences.  Most notably, if the size of the symbol is changed, and the anchor point is not using an absolute X/Y location, but a proportional one.